# SAS: multiply rows according to value

Tags: sas, datastep

I have the following sample data frame:

```
DATA queries;
INPUT id :$12. type :$3000. count :3.;
INFILE DATALINES DSD;
DATALINES;
1, Theft, 3
2, Assault, 3
3, Murder, 1
4, Fraud, 1
;
RUN;
```

But I'd rather have each row repeated n times (according to the value of the `count`-variable). So the result should be:

```
id type    count
1  Theft   3
1  Theft   3    <- new
1  Theft   3    <- new
2  Assault 3
2  Assault 3    <- new
2  Assault 3    <- new
3  Murder  1
4  Fraud   1
```

Does anyone know how to multiply the rows in SAS?

Comment: Is there a reason you need to repeat the data rows according to the count value ?  SAS Procedures can use `WEIGHT <var>` and `FREQ <var>` statements to deal with weighted and presummarized (count) data.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
data want;
   set queries;
   do _N_ = 1 to count;
      output;
   end;
run;
```